# SQL Add column as a Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

Question:
Add a column MGR_ID to table SECTION and set it as a Foreign Key column that is related to the Primary Key column EMPLOYEE_ID in table EMPLOYEE

My attempted code:
ALTER TABLE section
ADD MGR_ID
FOREIGN KEY (MGR_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID);

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The syntax for adding a foreign key using MySQL is readily available through a Google search

Comment: Yes for adding a foreign key, but how would do it in one command, so that the column is created and also set as a foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE section 
ADD MGR_ID int, 
add FOREIGN KEY (MGR_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID);
```